# MVVM with Room and LiveData

Tags: android

My ViewModel class looks like this:

```
 public class ViewModelMainActivity extends AndroidViewModel {

    private LocalRepository localRepository;

    private LiveData<List<Task>> allJob;
    private LiveData<List<Task>> allShopping;
    private LiveData<List<Task>> allOther;

    public ViewModelMainActivity(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        localRepository = new LocalRepository(application);

        allJob = localRepository.getAllJob();
        allShopping = localRepository.getAllShopping();
        allOther = localRepository.getAllOther();
    }

    public void insert(Task task) {
        localRepository.insert(task);
    }

    public void delete(Task task) {
        localRepository.delete(task);
    }

    public LiveData<List<Task>> getAllJob() {
        return allJob;
    }

    public LiveData<List<Task>> getAllShopping() {
        return allShopping;
    }

    public LiveData<List<Task>> getAllOther() {
        return allOther;
    }
}
```

Then in MainActivity calls two methods:

```
 private void getAllJob() {

    viewModelMainActivity.getAllJob().observe(this, new Observer<List<Task>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Task> tasks) {

            if(tasks.size() == 0) {

                linearLayoutActivityMain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {

                linearLayoutActivityMain.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            taskAdapter.setAllJobTasks(tasks);
        }
    });
}

private void getAllShopping() {

    viewModelMainActivity.getAllShopping().observe(this, new Observer<List<Task>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Task> tasks) {

            Log.i("Size", "Shopping: " + String.valueOf(tasks.size()));
            if(tasks.size() == 0) {

                linearLayoutActivityMain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {

                linearLayoutActivityMain.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            taskAdapter.setCurrentTasks(tasks);
        }
    });
}
```

Why when I save a task:

```
viewModelMainActivity.insert(task);
```

e.g. to the job category, both onChanged methods are called, not just the onChanged method in getAllJob. 
How could I separate it? That only the onChanged method would be called for values ​​that have changed. Should I create separate ViewModels objects? But what about saving the task then? I would have to call the insert method three times for each object?

Comment: They are saved to the same table, and Room detects only if a table has been changed, re-evaluates the queries,and refreshes all 3 LiveData.

Comment: How could I separate these operations? Should I create three separate ViewModel objects?

Comment: That will not affect the refresh mechanism of Room. To make Room not refresh all 3 lists when saving a `Task`, they would need to be in 3 separate Table... :|